# Android BottomSheet: Is hiding under the toolbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I tried to use the new bottom sheet from the support library 23.2.0 to have a bottom sheet expand to full screen like suggested in the [design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-behavior)

This works very good but the bottom sheet goes *under my ActionBar* and under my tabs.

How is it possible to let the bottom sheet go over the toolbar? My menu is structured like this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/playerLayout"
        layout="@layout/player_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:model="@{model}"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `fitSystemWindows` to the include layout that has the behavior?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `AppBarLayout` has a default elevation of `4dp` (the dimension resource value `design_appbar_elevation`).

By default `CoordinatorLayout`, like any `FrameLayout`, will layout elements with higher elevation before lower elevation on API 21 and higher devices.

Try adding `android:elevation="@dimen/design_appbar_elevation"` to your layout.

Note that the elevation of a modal bottom sheet is `@dimen/design_bottom_sheet_modal_elevation` == `16dp`

Comment: I made it work, thanks! Please edit: The elevation has to be added to the root of the layout that is included. Not within the <include> tag!

Comment: @ianhanniballake Bottom sheet not working for me in pre lollipop devices?

Comment: Can't we just simply hide the app bar when the bottom sheet is expanded to make compatible with pre-Lollipop devices?

Comment: @chubbsondubs - pre-Lollipop, views later in your xml file are already put at a higher level, so just declaring your bottom sheet after your `AppBarLayout` should be enough?

Comment: @ianhanniballake  what an useful information about CoordinatorLayout thanks

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: This is a nice solution. Is it possible to collide both - BottomSheet and AppBarLayout? I mean no overlapping to each other, the BottomSheet will stop scrolling upwards if it touches AppBarLayout.

Answer (score 2):

If the above answer doesn't help, try to set to your BottomSheet:

```
 android:elevation="@dimen/design_appbar_elevation"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

**and** create your Fragment such way:

```
videoFragment = VideoFragment.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.video_fragment, videoFragment)
                .commit();
```

not like this: <s>`videoFragment = (VideoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment);`</s>
For example I have such layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activity_background">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="@dimen/design_appbar_elevation"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and it doesn't work without specified things