# Make bottomSheetDialog full screen over status bar

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

I recently used android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment. I wanted to do something which is similar to the Google contact app, its BottomSheet can overlay the toolbar and statusbar. However, when I use the BottomSheetDialogFragment to implement this, it turns out to this:
[image: My Implementation]

As you can see the activity's toolbar is still visible. Here is my code of the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
public class KeyDetailFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.sheet_key, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        View parent = (View) contentView.getParent();
        parent.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(parent);
        contentView.measure(0, 0);
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(contentView.getMeasuredHeight());

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
        if (params.getBehavior() instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
                 ((BottomSheetBehavior)params.getBehavior()).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        }
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        parent.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

I referred to the source and I found an attribute interests me:

```
private static int getThemeResId(Context context, int themeId) {
    if (themeId == 0) {
        // If the provided theme is 0, then retrieve the dialogTheme from our theme
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(
                R.attr.bottomSheetDialogTheme, outValue, true)) {
            themeId = outValue.resourceId;
        } else {
            // bottomSheetDialogTheme is not provided; we default to our light theme
            themeId = R.style.Theme_Design_Light_BottomSheetDialog;
        }
    }
    return themeId;
}
```

the attribute `bottomSheetDialogTheme` here may change the bottom sheet's style but I don't know how to change it, and I doubt whether this would work. Can someone give me solution about achieving it that it can overlay the toolbar and statusbar?

Comment: Same issue, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @nipun.birla No, I haven't found it yet though it had passed for about 3 months

Comment: I think the reason is elevation. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711808/android-bottomsheet-is-hinding-under-the-toolbar.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. but not able to find a good solution.

Comment: Try read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68695862/14432480) article - it helped me so much

Answer (score 21):

Try this. It works for me.

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View inflatedView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_coupon, null);
    dialog.setContentView(inflatedView);


    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) inflatedView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

    if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
    }

    View parent = (View) inflatedView.getParent();
    parent.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(parent);
    inflatedView.measure(0, 0);
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(screenHeight);

    if (params.getBehavior() instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior)params.getBehavior()).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
    }

    params.height = screenHeight;
    parent.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: One thing to note with this solution is the displayMetrics.heightPixels will include the notification tray height so this will cut off the bottom slightly. I used this to calculate the height of the notification tray.

`private int getStatusBarHeight() {
        Rect rectangle = new Rect();
        Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
        return rectangle.top;
    }`

Comment: Edit:
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
To:
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()

Comment: Is it handle able with coordinator layout and appbar in xml?

Answer (score 2):

Was not able to find the solution to this problem, but can suggest an alternate that helped me serve the same purpose. Here's the reference :
http://www.hidroh.com/2016/06/17/bottom-sheet-everything/

The article explains creating a bottom sheet activity and adding the backdrop shadow with it.

Comment: The given reference is surely an alternative way to my purpose, adding a backdrop shadow is really tricky.

Comment: This answer does not address the problem in this question at all which is "Make bottomSheetDialog full screen over status bar". Nothing in that article helps with solving that, and it just wasted my time clicking into it. Also, pasting a link without any attempt at showing the answer here on SO is poor practice.

Answer (score 1):

This was easiest and worked for me, just extend BottomSheetDialog and set BottomSheetBehavior to **BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED**

**Little hack** is layout name `android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet` is taken from android support design library

```
class BottomSheetDialogExpanded(context: Context) : BottomSheetDialog(context) {

    private lateinit var mBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<FrameLayout>

    override fun setContentView(view: View) {
        super.setContentView(view)
        val bottomSheet = window.decorView.findViewById<View>(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout
        mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        mBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }
}
```