# Is there any way to draw BottomSheetDialogFragment behind the status bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I'm looking for a solution to draw my BottomSheetDialogFragment behind the status bar. I tried to override styles:

```
<style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet</item>
</style>
```

but nothing works. 
My parent layout is `fitSystemWindows="true"`

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my BottomSheetDialogFragment is fully expanded and `MATCH_PARENT`. Maybe there is different soultion to get a bottom sheet behavior on the fragment without extending from BottomSheetDialogFragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make bottomSheetDialog full screen over status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424964/make-bottomsheetdialog-full-screen-over-status-bar)